# What is the reason for a wide B$_S$ peak in dimuon plot?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, elementary-particles

Why is the B$_s$ meson peak in dimuon invariant mass spectrum wider than the others? Upsilon meson has a lifetime of several orders of magnitude shorter, which by my intution should lead the wider peak.

[image]

> Fig 3.8 [.Dimuon mass](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2205870/files/CERN-THESIS-2016-084.pdf) distribution collected with various dimuon triggers, during the 25 ns running period at 13 TeV in 2015.  The coloured paths correspond to dedicated dimuon triggers with low $p_T$ thresholds, in specific mass windows, while the light gray continuous distribution represents events collected with  a dimuon trigger with high $p_T$ thresholds

Comment: canyou give a link for the plot?

Comment: I found it in a thesis https://cds.cern.ch/record/2205870/files/CERN-THESIS-2016-084.pdf . fig 3.8

Answer (score 1):

There is no $B_s$ peak in this plot, and nor would you expect there to be. The decay $B_s \to \mu^+ \mu^-$ is very rare, with a branching fraction of about $2\times 10^{-9}$.

The legend on the plot is a strong clue to what is happening. Each colour is a different dimuon trigger. With the exception of the grey 'double muon inclusive', they each have a different invariant mass window. Within these windows, events are selected with greater efficiency, which appears as a step function on top of the 'double muon inclusive' distribution.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the caption it is evident that this is a composite plot. If you notice , there is a flat background around below each resonance ( cut off from that particular experiments data),on the background the resonance peak appears, or not, as in the case of the $B_s$. It is flat because no signal was found when looking with an appropriate trigger at that region. Only the pointed figures have a signal over a flat background.

The general gray background and figures are the ones to look at for resonances. The colored are specialized looks with more data at that area.