# Normalisation in Particle Physics

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I have Signal and background plots of some parameter(like Energy) on same canvas. Now I read that for normalisation, I have to multiply signal by $N_{signal}$ and background by $N_{bcg}$. 
(By $N$ I mean number of events)

I did not understand how this works. I thought that we have to divide both signal and background by $N_{signal} + N_{bcg}$.
Could someone help me to figure out the first case?
Thanks!

Comment: can you give a link to the plot? particle plots get quite complicated and the context is important, and the figure caption.

Comment: @annav  I do not have a specific plot.. But I attended a kind of meeting where I had the MC bjet and non-bjet distribution of some parameter which was later supposed to be used for some regression anallysis. But initially, I was first told to plot bjet and non-bjet distribution for that input variable and normalize them using the method I stated above. Is this information enough to deduce something...

Comment: This is an example of composite plots used which have no meaning if one does not have a figure caption https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398045/what-is-the-reason-for-a-wide-b-s-peak-in-dimuon-plot  . This is my answer . https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398045/what-is-the-reason-for-a-wide-b-s-peak-in-dimuon-plot/398260#398260  . For this composite plot one really needs the  figure caption. It seems to me you are also talking of a composite plot.